# Call an action in dropdownlist changed and send a model to view

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I'm trying to call a control action in dropdownlist selected  item changed and i do it using jquery:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedItemType.RowId, new SelectList(Model.ItemTypes, "RowId", "ItemTypeName")
                , htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control SelectList",@id="itemTypesDropDown", style = "height:300px", @size = 5
                }))
```

And

```
 $("#itemTypesDropDown").change(function () {
        var selectedValue = $('#itemTypesDropDown').val();
        $.post('@Url.Action("Select", "Home")', { selectedRowId: selectedValue }, function (data) {
        });
    });
```

and the control action is:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Select(long selectedRowId)
    {
        SetIndexViewDatas();

        var itemtypemodel = new ItemTypeViewModel
        {
            ItemTypes = _db.Inv_ItemType.Select(x => x).ToList(),
            SelectedItemType = _db.Inv_ItemType.FirstOrDefault()
        };
        return View("Index", itemtypemodel);
    }
```

and index.cshtml:

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group verticalAlign">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedItemType.ItemTypeName, "Attribute Name", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4 lable" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedItemType.ItemTypeName, "Attribute Name", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedItemType.ItemTypeName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
```

It works fine,after selected item changed it calls`select` action and post `itemtypemodel` to `index` view,but the problem is it doesn't load data in the `index`,where am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You making an ajax call, which means you stay on the same page. Your method needs to return a partial view, and really should be a GET. Then you need to update the DOM with the html your returning

```
public ActionResult Select(long selectedRowId)
{
    ....
    return PartialView("Index", itemtypemodel);
}
```

In the view, include an element as a placeholder to render the partial view you return

```
<div id="myContent"></div>
```

and modify the script to

```
$("#itemTypesDropDown").change(function () {
    $.post('@Url.Action("Select", "Home")', { selectedRowId: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
        $('#myContent').html(data);
    });
});
```

Alternatively, if you do not want to update the current page, but instead want to redirect to another page, do not use ajax (just use a normal submit and redirect).

Comment: Do i have to load a partialview?Isn't there any way to update current page?because this part of page is fixed and if i use a partial view i have to change all of my other actions to load this partial view and ai also have to load it in page load.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your last comment. If you want to update the existing page with new content based on the selected option, then you must return a partial view based on that content. But the fact you are returning a view named "Index" suggests that your really wanting to redirect to another page - `Index.cshtml` (no one names a partial view `Index.cshtml`)

Comment: Index.cshtml is the current page that hold the dropdownlist.

Comment: Attempting to return the same page makes no sense. Hard to know what you really want to do but you need to read the last paragraph of my answer - If you want to regenerate the whole view again, there is no point using ajax, just do a normal submit and redirect to the `Index()` GET method

Comment: Its a very simple senario,assume i have a dropdownlist in the current page(index),and  i also have some input in the same page(index) that i want to update with selected item of the dropdownlist.

Comment: If that's all you want to do, then you don't need ajax at all - you can just get the `.text()` property of the selected option and update the textbox. But what you saying does not really make sense

Comment: I want to update the entire model(selected item of dropdown)of index view.its a single view that i am doing CRUD operation in it.as i understood the only way is to use partial view.

Comment: Still unclear, but my answer is correct based on your question, but it appears your question is wrong (at least unclear) so I'll delete this later.